# How to convert List of List to flat List from Class Object output in Python without getting error "'User' object is not iterable"

Tags: python

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, dbcname, username, password):
        self.id = id
        self.dbacname = dbcname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{[self.username, self.password, self.dbcname]}'

users = []
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc1', username='user0', password='pwd1'))
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc2', username='user1', password='pwd2'))
print(users[1])
```

## it gives output as ['user1', 'pwd2', 'dbc2']

## but I wanted to know how to access the value user1

Comment: Please post your code so it's readable. Repaste it, then highlight it and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Did you try `users[1][0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the attribute you created

```
users = []
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc1', username='user0', password='pwd1'))
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc2', username='user1', password='pwd2'))
print(users[1].username)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just add the extension *(you also have a typo where `bdcname` became `dbaname`)*:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, dbcname, username, password):
        self.id = id
        self.dbcname = dbcname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{[self.username, self.password, self.dbcname]}'

users = []
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc1', username='user0', password='pwd1'))
users.append(User(id=1, dbcname='dbc2', username='user1', password='pwd2'))
print(users[1].username)
```

Output:

```
user1
```

Comment: This way will work if we create List from direct data instead of creating it from the above CLASS..Due to LIST creation of CLASS the error occurred as 'User' Object is not subscriptable. When I try to print(users[1][0]